# Windows Mobile to Windows CE, VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile

I'd written an application in VB .NET for the Windows Mobile 5.0, yesterday a customer wants to use the application on there existing Symbol MC90XX that runs Windows CE 5.0.
Can someone tell me what is the best way to convert from VB .net Mobile to VB.net CE?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just change your deployment platform from Windows mobile 5.0 to Windows CE 5.0? and see how it goes.

Comment: I'd do that, and fix compiler errors. Everything else *should* be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to convert. If it is not present already on the device, you can download and install the compact framework there.

Windows Mobile 5 and 6 are just a extra customization focused for phones over Windows CE 5. They are binary compatible, providing that you are using the same processor family.

Comment: well one of the biggest problem is that I was creating a text file and using the e-mail inside my program to send the file. I don't know if there is a version of pocket office for CE.
I created a new project for CE and copy all the files from the Mobile and add the references needed, but I have about 200 errors in the error list. I need to go deep and study more. I am also going to do what you mention and try to deploy the one I have on the CE to see what happen.

thanks for answering
Oscar

Comment: If you´re having issues such as Can´t execute the application, you can also try to use Dependency Walker. I know that is for X86/WinXP+ but it works with ce binaries as well.